# How to make mongoose+typescript check for document type?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I define a model in typescript like this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

export const User = model<IUser>('user', UserSchema)

export interface IUser {
  username: string
}
```

However when I try to create a new user this is somehow ok:

```
User.create({
  username: 43
})
```

And this is ok too

```
User.create({
  random_field: 'anything'
})
```

Is it possible to make typescript disallow invalid types there?

Comment: Sadly no. The `User.create` function accepts an `AnyObject` which basically allows objects of any shape to be passed to the function. The only thing you could do is create a wrapper function for the document creation.

Comment: Kinda defeats the whole purpose of type annotation, doesn’t it?

Comment: well when you use `User.find()` or other query methods, you will have good typings. I don't know why they chose to include `AnyObject` in the `create` method